# Docker container won't start the mysql-client

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:5.6

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=some_db
ENV MYSQL_USER=some_user
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass
```

i use this command to run a container

```
docker run --name mymysql --rm -it -p 3306:3306 mysql
```

the script start and stop here.

```
    ... some logs
    MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.

    2018-06-15 12:15:49 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
    2018-06-15 12:15:49 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.6.40) starting as process 1 ...
    2018-06-15 12:15:49 1 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
    2018-06-15 12:15:49 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
    2018-06-15 12:15:49 1 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
    2018-06-15 12:15:49 1 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
    2018-06-15 12:15:49 1 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
    2018-06-15 12:15:49 1 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
    2018-06-15 12:15:49 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
    2018-06-15 12:15:49 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
    2018-06-15 12:15:49 1 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
    2018-06-15 12:15:49 1 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2018-06-15 12:15:49 1 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
    2018-06-15 12:15:49 1 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
    2018-06-15 12:15:49 1 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
    2018-06-15 12:15:49 1 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.40 started; log sequence number 1625997
    2018-06-15 12:15:49 1 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
    2018-06-15 12:15:49 1 [Note] IPv6 is available.
    2018-06-15 12:15:49 1 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
    2018-06-15 12:15:49 1 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
    2018-06-15 12:15:49 1 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
    2018-06-15 12:15:49 1 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@1804588a972e' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
    2018-06-15 12:15:49 1 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
    2018-06-15 12:15:49 1 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
    Version: '5.6.40'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
....NOTHING HAPPENS
```

I need a command that run a container and start directly the mysql-client.

Comment: type `EXPOSE 3306`

Comment: I try it with EXPSE 3306 im Dockerfile and i got ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: can i see `docker ps` output ?

Comment: From the logs, we can see that MySQL is indeed started and is waiting for connections. Could you describe your issue with a bit more details ?

Comment: Is the issue resolved? @em